# php Laravel ~ Attribute [controller] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

I am trying to set up an Route Controller in my Laravel project and I have set up the controller and also the route.

However, when I load the route in the `web.php` then it produces an error when I try to navigate to that page in the browser of `Attribute [controller] does not exist`

Here is the code..

```
<?php
   namespace CMS\Http\Controllers\Auth;

   use CMS\Http\Controllers\Controller;
   use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

use AuthenticatesUsers {
    logout as performLogout;
}

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 */
protected $redirectTo;

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 */

public function __construct()
{
    $this->redirectTo = route('backend.dashboard');
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}

public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->performLogout($request);
    return redirect()->route('auth.login');
}
}
```

And then in the web.php I have this...

```
Route::controller('auth', 'Auth\LoginController', [
    'getLogin' => 'auth.login'
]);
```

Comment: Route::controller('auth', 'Auth.LoginController', [
    'getLogin' => 'auth.login'
]);    ------>> TRY THIS

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar This doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: The controller method is deprecated since Laravel 5.3. But now, you can use the resource method, which is meant for the same purpose as the controller method: ...  Like This ::    Route::resource('datatables', 'HomeController');

Comment: Now I get an error that show() does not exist.

Comment: You have to Change the Routes also as Per your routes.. you change it ..

Comment: Yeah I did do, I removed the function show() for some unknown reason.. I got it working now. Thank you.

Comment: okk :) Your Welcome .....

Answer (score 29):

The controller method is deprecated since Laravel 5.3. But now, you can use the resource method, which is meant for the same purpose as the controller method.

Like This:

```
Route::resource('auth', 'LoginController');
```

or

```
Route::get('/auth','LoginController');

Route::post('/auth','LoginController');
```

Comment: In laravel 5.2 , controller method is working, now by using controller method  in laravel 5.4 , it gives the same attribute controller error. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hm that's odd, the Laravel 8 router documentation uses it for routing by groups: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-groups