# Laravel 8 Attribute [controller] does not exist

Tags: laravel

In my route I want to create a group.

```php
Route::controller(ProductController::class)->group(function () {
    dd('Hello World');
});
```

And get the following error message: `Attribute [controller] does not exist.`.

Although it is in the Laravel 8 documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-controllers I assume that the function does not exist in Laravel 8. **Probably an mistake in the documentation!?!?**

**Note:** In Laravel 9 it would work.

Comment: I saw that this feature was introduced last week in Laravel 9. Not sure why is documented as it is for Laravel 8. Anyway, did you add the `use App\Http\Controllers\ProductController;` at the beginning?

Comment: @Luciano I wonder as well. Up to Laravel 5.3 there was apparently the route controller method. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43572805/14807111

Answer (score 2):

In the early versions of Laravel 8, there is no Route Group Controller they introduce it in laravel version 8.80
please check your laravel version to see if it's the 8.80 version or higher
and if it's higher

As of Documentation

```
Route::controller(OrderController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::get('/orders/{id}', 'show');
    Route::post('/orders', 'store');
});
```

you didn't mention any routes inside your group like

```
Route::controller(OrderController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::get('/orders', function(){
     dd("hello world!")
     });
});
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M9TkLVrVfWs

https://laravel-news.com/laravel-8-80-0

Comment: That could be the problem. Can you provide a link where you found it this information please?

Comment: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-8-80-0

Comment: I edited the answer you can find the links